# Which statistical test to use for this dataset?

Tags: regression, prediction

I have a dataset that I need to analyse in order to determine if the measurements taken can be used to predict tool type. The independent variable (tool type) has 6 groups. From each of these tools 8 marks were made and the 6 different measurements were taken from each toolmark (288 measurements in total). These groups are normally distributed. Which statistical test will enable me to use some or all of the data to classify future measurements into tool type, I assume some form of regression model? Alternatively, is it possible to establish which combination of the 6 measurements is the most predictive?

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals? What are the groups? What are these variables? Are they normally distributed? Do you need to group the data using the variables, or do you really need to select only some of the variables (how many? why?)? Etc. This is too vague to be well answered at present.

Comment: Do you really need a *test*, or do you want to be able to classify future toolmarks as having come from a particular tool type?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I fully understand the structure of your dataset but it sounds like a classification tree model may be what you are looking for. You may want to have a look at packages like `tree`, `rpart` or `party`.

Comment: That won't yield a statistical test, if that's what the OP really needs.

Comment: True. I didn't really read the question as really requiring a test as it mostly speaks of classification. Anyway, I would run this in a 10-fold cross-validation or leave-one-out setting to get an estimate of performance and if a test is desired one could follow up with a permutation test.
@Kirsty: Maybe you could give us some more information about your needs. Do you need a test? And if you do: what hypothesis would you like to test?